# Increasing QueryString max length

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, query-string

I have a queryString which is around 2500 characters long, over the default 2048 limit.

Now I've changed the settings in web.config as suggested:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxQueryStringLength="204800" maxUrlLength="409600"/>
```

Still comes back with error that the string is too long.

I've also changed those settings in IIS6 -> Request Filetering -> Query Strings -> Edit Feature Settings to the same values and still no joy.

The browser is IE11.

Can the maxQueryStringLength actually be changed?

Unfortunately I cannot limit the amount of text in the query string so that is not an option.

Comment: I don't think that can be changed. It's browser limitation not asp.net problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change the query string length of the browser.

The limitation are in the following question on SO
[What is the maximum possible length of a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string)

Comment: Hmm after playing around with the settings I noticed that now it will actually execute the page with the querystring but it does get clipped in the address bar.